# Python csv file writing blanks?

Tags: python, csv

I looked really hard, and still can't understand what is going wrong here. I'm trying to extract data from a website, yet when it comes to writing that data into a csv file, even though the code seems correct, nothing is appended into the file. Can someone PLEASE explain why!!??

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_past_and_future_population#Sources"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
writer = csv.writer(open("/Users/alihamed/Desktop/PopulationsOfCountries.csv", 'w'))

data = []
with open('PopulationsOfCountries'+'.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter =',')

    for tables in soup.findAll("table",{"class": "sortable wikitable"}):
        print("In!") 
        #writer.writerow(data)
        #f.flush()
        #writer.writerow(data)
        '''write table contents from here
           append newline
        '''
        for tr in tables.findAll("tr"):
           # data.append("\n")
            for td in tr.findAll("td"):               
                #print td.string                                    
                data.append(td.string)
                #writer.writerow(data)
                '''

                '''
            writer.writerow(data)   
            f.flush()            
    #print(data)         
f.close()
```

Comment: I suggest you learn some debugging skills.

Comment: Have you tried `print`ing what you think you're writing to a file?

Comment: Yeah, and it works. The data is all their just not writing...

Comment: Why do you have 2 `writer` objects?

Comment: @Denziloe: well, the code here is full of commented out `print` statements, so presumably they have. The writing works just fine (albeit that there is an issue with `data` only ever being appended to), it is just not writing to the location they are thinking is written to.

Comment: @Peter Good catch, that was the problem all along!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open two file objects:

```
writer = csv.writer(open("/Users/alihamed/Desktop/PopulationsOfCountries.csv", 'w'))
```

and then

```
with open('PopulationsOfCountries'+'.csv','w') as f:
```

The latter is the one you write data to (in ever-growing rows, as `data` is never cleared after writing to the CSV).

You are probably looking at the *first* file, on your Desktop, while the other file is created in your current working directory (which can be anywhere, you don't show how you run this code). That file on your desktop is indeed going to be empty.

Open your file **once**, with a full path. And your `data` list after writing out a row, or better still, just use a generator to send the cell text straight to the `writer.writerow()` method:

```
path = "/Users/alihamed/Desktop/PopulationsOfCountries.csv"
with open(path, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for tables in soup.findAll("table",{"class": "sortable wikitable"}):
        for tr in tables.findAll("tr"):
            writer.writerow(td.string for td in tr.find_all('td'))
```

There's no need to call `.close()` on the file either; `with` takes care of that for you.